# What is (Xcode: Wildcard AppID) in my iOS Provisioning Portal?

Tags: xcode, ios, wildcard, provisioning, portal

Suddenly I saw now a new App ID in my (iOS Provisioning Portal) with description of (Xcode: Wildcard AppID), is it added recently by Apple or by me? But I never added it!

And there is no (configure) link for this App, only (details) link where I can't configure anything!

Regards

Comment: That's probably connected to the Xcode team provisioning profile that Xcode sets up automatically.

Comment: if the Erik B's answer helped you, then mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xcode now creates a provisioning profile automatically, so that you don't have to. This wildcard app id is part of that provisioning profile.

Comment: What is the benefit of this Wildcard app?

Comment: @DeZingy That you don't have to create a provisioning profile yourself. The provisioning profile needs an app id, so Xcode creates a generic one, the wildcard app id. If you've already created a provisioning profile manually, you won't have much use for this wildcard app id, but having it will not hurt you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand. Would that mean, that if I create a new AppID in the future, I do not need to create a Provisioning Profile ? Apple will create one for me ?? I don't get it !

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it means that you can create one provisioning profile for a device that can be used to test multiple applications (rather than creating a new provisioning profile for each device AND each application).